# Beginning Python Lottery Function

Tags: python

I am attempting to create a function that evaluate user input against a randomly generated 'winner' sequence. The code will run fine until after the user's input has been entered, where it will stop. The editor I use is a bit strange as well, so the indentation will be off here, however, I promise that it is NOT the issue. Sorry about that. Thank you

```
from __future__ import print_function
import random
import sys

minimum, maximum = 1,69

def playPowerBall():
  instruction = "Please pick your {} number, between 1 and 69:"
  tickets = []
  for s in ('1st', '2nd', '3rd', '4th', '5th', '6th'):
    ticket = int(input(instruction.format(s)))
    tickets.append(ticket)

  range = (1,69)

  if any(ticket < minimum or ticket > maximum for ticket in tickets):
    print('One or more of the inputted numbers is not between 1-69. Please restart the function and try again.')
    sys.exit()

  winners = []

  for s in ('1st', '2nd', '3rd', '4th', '5th', '6th'):
    winner = random.sample(range(0,69), 6)
    winners.append(winner)

def matches(tickets, winners):
  score = 0

  for number in tickets:
    if number in winners:
      score += 1
    else:
      score += 0

    return score

  if 3 <= score:
    print('You picked at least three winning numbers, please claim your cash prize.')
  else:
    print('You do not have a winning combination. Would you like to play Powerball again? (Y/N)')
    response = str(input('Y/N:'))

    if response == 'Y':
      sys.restart()
    else:
      sys.exit()
```

Comment: What is the issue you are having? What is the entrypoint?

Comment: First of, range = (1,69) is a bad thing todo, because you create a new variable the overwrites Pythons range function. If I call your playPowerBall() it crashes because of this. Second, once the user enters his numbers, you generate your winners, but don't do anything with them. You do not print them, nor return them, that's why you do not see any results.

Comment: After I input the 6 numbers in the ticket portion, I get File "main.py", line 20 in playPowerBall, it says something about tuple needing to be integers or slicing.

Comment: As I said, you overwrite Pythons range function. I don't know why you create this variable, since you don't seem to use it. Simply delete the line with range=(1,69)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting builtin function `range` whith the statement `range = (1, 69)` and then you do `winner = random.sample(range(0,69), 6)` so, you are trying to call the tuple `(1, 69)`. If you remove such statement `range = (0, 69)`, the error goes away. There are other issues in you code, you have to call `matches` at the end of `playPowerBall`, you have to remove the `return` statement from method `matches` and `sys` doesn't have a `restart` function but you can call recursively to `playPowerBall`:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import random
import sys

minimum, maximum = 1,69

def playPowerBall():
  instruction = "Please pick your {} number, between 1 and 69:"
  tickets = []
  for s in ('1st', '2nd', '3rd', '4th', '5th', '6th'):
    ticket = int(input(instruction.format(s)))
    tickets.append(ticket)

  if any(ticket < minimum or ticket > maximum for ticket in tickets):
    print('One or more of the inputted numbers is not between 1-69. Please restart the function and try again.')
    sys.exit()

  winners = []

  for s in ('1st', '2nd', '3rd', '4th', '5th', '6th'):
    winner = random.sample(range(0,69), 6)
    winners.append(winner)

  matches(tickets, winners)

def matches(tickets, winners):
  score = 0

  for number in tickets:
    if number in winners:
      score += 1
    else:
      score += 0

  if 3 <= score:
    print('You picked at least three winning numbers, please claim your cash prize.')
  else:
    print('You do not have a winning combination. Would you like to play Powerball again? (Y/N)')
    response = str(input('Y/N:'))

    if response == 'Y':
      playPowerBall()
    else:
      sys.exit()

playPowerBall()
```

Comment: The range appears to still have an issue. It says that 'type' object is not subscriptable.

Comment: winner = random.sample(range(0,69), 6)

Comment: It says that 'tuple' object is not callable.

Comment: That was the first issue, just remove the statement `range = (1, 69)`

Comment: Yes, but then, the initial issue comes back again, where the function just stops. I am trying to get it to judge whether there is a winning combination made.

Comment: @yiekeycalzone I posted my code, let me know if this works for you

Comment: @yiekeycalzone in that case, please, mark my answer as accepted (green checkmark) and upvote it, Thnx in advance!